# Blender 2.81 - How can an Active mesh interact with a Passive mesh without the Active mesh bouncing away from the Passive mesh?

Tags: modeling, animation, physics, eevee-render-engine, rigid-body-simulation

For example, I modelled this picture frame. A bolt is used to hang the picture no problem. But when I apply the "Active" physics to the frame and the "Passive" physics to the bolt, the frame just bounces away from the bolt, as shown in the picture below.
[image: A rendered picture, demonstrating what happens when an Active "picture frame" interacts with a Passive "bolt".]
Is there some sort of way where the Passive bolt can go inside the Active frame without the frame being ejected from the bolt? (As shown in the picture below, with no physics applied)
[image: A rendered picture without the physics applied.]

Comment: Have you tried using *Mesh* as [Collision Shape](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/rigid_body/properties.html)?

Comment: I tried your method of the Collision Shape as "Mesh", and it worked. Thank you very much for your help!